# How to use Spring's JdbcTemplate to connect to a simple MySql database?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am trying to use Spring's JdbcTemplate Class to connect to a simple MySql database based on [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) tutorial. In fact, I used their project setup:

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The Lombok dependency is for getters and setters.

Then there is the Application class:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating tables");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("drop table customers if exists");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("create table customers(" +
                "id serial, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255))");
    }
}
```

And finally a Customer pojo:

```
package test;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    private long id;
    private String firstName, lastName;
}
```

For datasource configuration I have an application.properties file in my resources folder:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

The database is up and running and still the autowirig dosen't seem to work.
Here is the exception I get when I try to run it:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.
BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate test.Application.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at test.Application.main(Application.java:12)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate test.Application.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which
 qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
```

What I find curious is the fact that if I replace the mysql-connector-java dependeny with a com.h2database, it just works (as in the spring example).

Do I need to configure the mysql datasource in a dirfferent way?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, be sure that `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` is enabled for you. Add `--debug` `java` argument when you run your boot application and take a look to the logs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add the dependency below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which will autoconfigure the Datasource

Comment: That worked! Datasource is configured. I found another mistake, however: the first sql statement has to be: `create table if not exists customers` to be working in mysql. cheers