# Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, db2, spring-jdbc

I am new to Spring and am having the following problem, can anyone assist me please?

I am trying to get the Spring Guide [gs-relational-data-access](http://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) project to work with a local db2 instance instead of the embedded h2 database, but it fails. I have added the drivers for db2 to the build path and have removed the h2 dependency from the `pom.xml` file. I have also added the db2 connection properties to the `application.properties` file in the classpath root.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2//localhost:50000/SAMPLE
spring.datasource.username=dsuser
spring.datasource.password=dspass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource
spring.datasource.schema=SPRING
```

Using the embedded h2 instance it works fine, but I need to build an application that works with a db2 instance.

Full stack trace:
    
    Exception in thread "main"     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate hello.Application.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
2015-08-19 16:19:07.465 ERROR 12016 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate hello.Application.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate hello.Application.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 17 common frames omitted
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate hello.Application.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 17 more

I have installed the db2 dependencies with maven and added them to the pom.xml

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=db2jcc4.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc4 -Dversion=10.1 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=db2jcc_license_cu.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc_license_cu  -Dversion=10.1 -Dpackaging=jar

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
        <version>10.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Your `spring.datasource.driver-class` isn't pointing to a driver class but a datasource class... Quite different thing. Please add the FULL stack trace instead of a snippet.

Comment: As @M.Deinum said,your spring.datasource.driver-class isn't pointing to a driver class of the db2 database. The correct driver should be **com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver**. the stacktrace said that Spring couldn't find a correct implementation of the driver in order to instanciate the class member hello.Application.jdbcTemplate

Comment: Changed the driver to com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver but still get similar stack trace:

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace and your java class containing the @autowired annotation on a jdbcTemplate attribute.

Comment: Are you pointing the `application.properties` with an archive xml of spring configuration?

Comment: did you add this dependency to your maven pom.xml? 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>` see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902140/how-to-use-springs-jdbctemplate-to-connect-to-a-simple-mysql-database) it may help you

Comment: dependencies include spring-boot-starter and spring-jdbc, do I need to include the db2 drivers in the dependencies, they are only in the project build path?

Comment: Tupac - I understood that if the application.properties file was in the root folder, the properties would be automatically read by Spring and the dataSource evaluated from the driver-class-name. No XML files used.

Comment: another suggestion, remove the spring-jdbc dependency as it will be pulled in by spring-boot-starter-jdbc. which maven version are you using?

Comment: tried removing the spring-jdbc dependency but errored as JdbcTemplate not recognised, maven 3.1