# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'

Tags: spring, maven, jdbc, spring-boot, vaadin

I've tried to create [simple webapps](http://start.spring.io/) springboot with dependencies: web, postgresql, jdbc, vaadin.
When start to run my apps, the apps won't start and there are exception thrown.
The exception telling "..no qualifying bean of type JdbcTemplate".
Some suggestion in stackoverflow to add artifact [spring-boot-starter-jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902140/how-to-use-springs-jdbctemplate-to-connect-to-a-simple-mysql-database), but my pom already did it and still won't work.

Below my config

src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sehati
spring.datasource.username=sehati
spring.datasource.password=password
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sehatigroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>siapotek</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>siapotek</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
 
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
         
         <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         -->
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SiaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SiaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

VadinUI:

```
@SpringUI
@Theme("valo")
public class SehatiDashboardUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new Label("Hello World"));
    }
}
```

Spring component:

```
@Component
public class LookupService {
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    public List<Lookup> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select id, type, label, name from lookup", 
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Lookup(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("type"), rs.getString("label"), rs.getString("label")));
    }
}
```

The console output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

2016-08-15 07:03:09.329  INFO 1387 --- [           main] com.sehatigroup.SiaApplication           : Starting SiaApplication on learn2fly with PID 1387 (/home/hameed/workspace/siapotek/target/classes started by hameed in /home/hameed/workspace/siapotek)
2016-08-15 07:03:09.333  INFO 1387 --- [           main] com.sehatigroup.SiaApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-15 07:03:09.530  INFO 1387 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5656be13: startup date [Mon Aug 15 07:03:09 WIB 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-15 07:03:11.329  WARN 1387 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'com.vaadin.spring.VaadinConfiguration' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-08-15 07:03:11.892  INFO 1387 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-08-15 07:03:12.069  INFO 1387 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$666445bd] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-15 07:03:12.776  INFO 1387 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-15 07:03:12.795  INFO 1387 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-08-15 07:03:12.797  INFO 1387 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2016-08-15 07:03:12.931  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-08-15 07:03:12.932  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3414 ms
2016-08-15 07:03:13.065  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Registering Vaadin servlet
2016-08-15 07:03:13.065  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Servlet will be mapped to URLs [/vaadinServlet/*, /VAADIN/*]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.086  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Setting servlet init parameters
2016-08-15 07:03:13.086  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [productionMode] = [false]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.086  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [resourceCacheTime] = [3600]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.087  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [heartbeatInterval] = [300]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.087  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [closeIdleSessions] = [false]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.218  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.218  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.219  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.219  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.221  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.221  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.223  INFO 1387 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'springVaadinServlet' to [/vaadinServlet/*, /VAADIN/*]
2016-08-15 07:03:13.302  WARN 1387 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'lookupService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate': No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2016-08-15 07:03:13.307  INFO 1387 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-08-15 07:03:13.338  WARN 1387 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
2016-08-15 07:03:13.355 ERROR 1387 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'lookupService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate': No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sehatigroup.SiaApplication.main(SiaApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

And also i've try to use H2 database. My apps can started, but seemslike datasource connection always use pre-configured datasource from spring-boot-jdbc (`url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'`), even i've already described the new one in application.properties.

Could someone find what's wrong with my project?
Really appreciate your help.

Comment: There's something you're not showing. My best guess at this point is that you have two `DataSource` in your system. The configuration in `application.properties` will make sure to create a `DataSource` bean for you. Could it be that you're creating the datasource yourself? Run your app with "--debug" and you'll get a report that explains why the JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration wasn't enabled.

Comment: Hi @Stephane. Thank you for the clue. I have only one Datasource configured in application.properties and AFAIK no other datasource created. My complete eclipse project can be access [here] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgee2bgoc9hkrx8/siapotek.tar.gz?dl=0). Please kindly review my project.

Comment: I also try debug the project, but i have no idea with exception thrown in eclipse [console](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0ztkqme89tzukv/console.out?dl=0). One output line make me curious, it said "Skipped (empty) config file...", i've checked the  application.properties already contain datasource config

Comment: Uh? I downloaded the project and it works just fine for me. I could start the app and go to the home page. I could run the test. No exception.

Comment: Thanks @StephaneNicoll. It's sounds like 'environment' problem for me. I have clean the project, move project to other workspace..but still found the same problem. I use eclipse neon (4.6.0) with plugin: spring IDE 3.8.1. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've try new IDE (eclipse, sts), create new workspace, import the project, create new project but still face some problem.

Finally my apps can running well after removing my .m2 folder. But i still don't know what happened in my mvn repository.

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

    2016-08-16 06:14:42.381  INFO 2531 --- [           main] com.sehatigroup.SiaApplication           : Starting SiaApplication on learn2fly with PID 2531 (/home/hameed/workspace/siapotek/target/classes started by hameed in /home/hameed/workspace/siapotek)
    2016-08-16 06:14:42.382  INFO 2531 --- [           main] com.sehatigroup.SiaApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2016-08-16 06:14:42.382 DEBUG 2531 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.sehatigroup.SiaApplication
    2016-08-16 06:14:42.520 DEBUG 2531 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:/home/hameed/workspace/siapotek/target/classes/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
    2016-08-16 06:14:42.520 DEBUG 2531 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped (empty) config file 'file:/home/hameed/workspace/siapotek/target/classes/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties) for profile default
    2016-08-16 06:14:42.526  INFO 2531 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3590fc5b: startup date [Tue Aug 16 06:14:42 WIB 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    2016-08-16 06:14:42.529 DEBUG 2531 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3590fc5b: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@65f095f8: defining beans 

-----CUTTED_TEXT----8<

    =========================
    AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
    =========================


    Positive matches:
    -----------------

       AuthenticationManagerConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [objectPostProcessor] @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       BootGlobalAuthenticationConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)

       DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.sql.DataSource,org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType (OnClassCondition)

       DataSourceAutoConfiguration#dataSourceInitializer matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceConfiguration matched
          - supported DataSource class found (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition)
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource,javax.sql.XADataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource (OnClassCondition)
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.TomcatDataSourcePoolMetadataProviderConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource (OnClassCondition)

       DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)

       DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary candidate amongst the following [dataSource] (OnBeanCondition)

       DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration#transactionManager matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.TransactionManagementConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

       DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.ServletRegistration (OnClassCondition)
          - no DispatcherServlet found (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DefaultDispatcherServletCondition)

       DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.ServletRegistration (OnClassCondition)
          - no ServletRegistrationBean found (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationCondition)

       DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration#dispatcherServletRegistration matched
          - @ConditionalOnBean (names: dispatcherServlet; types: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [dispatcherServlet, dispatcherServlet] (OnBeanCondition)

       EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration matched
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

       EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

       ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#basicErrorController matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#conventionErrorViewResolver matched
          - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [dispatcherServlet] @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DefaultErrorViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#errorAttributes matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration matched
          - No error template view detected (ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.ErrorTemplateMissingCondition)
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration#beanNameViewResolver matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration#defaultErrorView matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: error; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       GenericCacheConfiguration matched
          - Automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

       HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter (OnClassCondition)
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration#characterEncodingFilter matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter (OnClassCondition)

       HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration#messageConverters matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter (OnClassCondition)

       HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration#stringHttpMessageConverter matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)


-----CUTTED_TEXT----8<


       JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.sql.DataSource (OnClassCondition)
          - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary candidate amongst the following [dataSource] (OnBeanCondition)

       JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration#jdbcTemplate matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration#namedParameterJdbcTemplate matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       JmxAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter (OnClassCondition)
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       JmxAutoConfiguration#mbeanExporter matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       JmxAutoConfiguration#mbeanServer matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.management.MBeanServer; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       JmxAutoConfiguration#objectNamingStrategy matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.ObjectNamingStrategy; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       MultipartAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver,javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement (OnClassCondition)
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       MultipartAutoConfiguration#multipartConfigElement matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       MultipartAutoConfiguration#multipartResolver matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       NoOpCacheConfiguration matched
          - Automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

       PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor (OnClassCondition)

       PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration#persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       RedisCacheConfiguration matched
          - Automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

       SecurityAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)

       SecurityAutoConfiguration#authenticationEventPublisher matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationEventPublisher; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       SecurityAutoConfiguration#securityProperties matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer,org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy (OnClassCondition)
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

       SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration#securityFilterChainRegistration matched
          - @ConditionalOnBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [springSecurityFilterChain] (OnBeanCondition)

       ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration matched
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

       ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration#serverProperties matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       SimpleCacheConfiguration matched
          - Automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

       SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration matched
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration#springApplicationAdminRegistrar matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity,org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint (OnClassCondition)
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration#ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$IgnoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.ApplicationWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter matched
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       TransactionAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)
          - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary candidate amongst the following [transactionManager] (OnBeanCondition)

       TransactionAutoConfiguration#transactionTemplate matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       VaadinAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI (OnClassCondition)

       VaadinServletConfiguration#vaadinServlet matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       WebClientAutoConfiguration.RestTemplateConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate (OnClassCondition)

       WebClientAutoConfiguration.RestTemplateConfiguration#restTemplateBuilder matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration#hiddenHttpMethodFilter matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration#httpPutFormContentFilter matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#requestContextFilter matched
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener,org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#viewResolver matched
          - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [defaultViewResolver, beanNameViewResolver, mvcViewResolver] @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: viewResolver; types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.FaviconConfiguration matched
          - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

       WebSocketAutoConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer (OnClassCondition)
          - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

       WebSocketAutoConfiguration.TomcatWebSocketConfiguration matched
          - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat,org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci (OnClassCondition)

       WebSocketAutoConfiguration.TomcatWebSocketConfiguration#websocketContainerCustomizer matched
          - Required JVM version 1.7 or newer found 1.8 (OnJavaCondition)
          - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: websocketContainerCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)


       -----CUTTED_TEXT----8<


    2016-08-16 06:14:47.958  INFO 2531 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
    2016-08-16 06:14:47.964  INFO 2531 --- [           main] com.sehatigroup.SiaApplication           : Started SiaApplication in 6.015 seconds (JVM running for 6.797)
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

It looks as though you haven't created a JdbcTemplate bean in any configuration class, so spring doesn't know what to inject into your JdbcTemplate when your application starts up.

Here's one example which shows how to set your JdbcTemplate from a datasource bean in your spring configuration: http://www.concretepage.com/spring/jdbc-template-spring-jdbc-integration-example

Comment: Hi Adam. Thank you for your advice. Since i use spring-boot-starter-jdbc, will jdbcTemplate bean created automatically?

Comment: Ah, it seems you're correct :) however I read the readme and it has the following info:

"Spring Boot spots H2, an in-memory relational database engine, and automatically creates a connection. Because we are using spring-jdbc, Spring Boot automatically creates a JdbcTemplate. The @Autowired JdbcTemplate field automatically loads it and makes it available."

Given it seems to need H2 to inject the JdbcTemplate, is there a reason you've commented this out in your pom.. ?

Comment: You don't need H2 to get a JdbcTemplate. As long as there is a datasource (on any database type), we'll auto-configure a JdbcTemplate.

Comment: @AdamSmith. About H2 in my pom, previously i've litle experiment using H2 driver to see whether spring-boot will use my application.properties or not. And i found spring-boot not use or read my application.properties file. I have configure jdbc url use H2 file (not in memory as default H2 datasource). When the apps started, it's said datasource use url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'. After that i commented H2 driver, and get back to PostgreSQL.