# Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. Application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Autoconfiguration file is not working in Spring-Boot application. Thrown Exception is below. How can I fix it?

Error creating bean with name 'jdbcConverter' defined in class path resource

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-24 17:27:34.100 ERROR 1532 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcConverter' parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@4ad3d266. Please provide a Dialect.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.sbjdbc.Azuzeen2Application.main(Azuzeen2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@4ad3d266. Please provide a Dialect.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1293) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@4ad3d266. Please provide a Dialect.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@4ad3d266. Please provide a Dialect.
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.lambda$getDialect$2(DialectResolver.java:75) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:74) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration.jdbcDialect(AbstractJdbcConfiguration.java:144) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$127b19f3.CGLIB$jdbcDialect$5(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$127b19f3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c02a4139.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$127b19f3.jdbcDialect(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource

Comment: Can you take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902140/how-to-use-springs-jdbctemplate-to-connect-to-a-simple-mysql-database)?

Comment: Or this https://vladmihalcea.com/jdbc-driver-connection-url-strings/